# Digitize graphs. Pull out data from points in a scatter plot

Tags: python, image-preprocessing

I have a project where I would like to extract data from a series of scatter plots that are image files (Jpeg or png). The plots are similar but the axes scales are not always exactly the same. I have looked online and there are some web app solutions that are very “manual” and require a lot of clicking. This would get tiresome if there are a lot of graphs.

Does anyone know of any solutions that are partly or wholly automated? A python API solution would be ideal but other languages are also ok.

Answer (score 0):

Digitizing Graph. I know a tool that can semi-automatically extract data, (scattered points and curves) from graph images within a few clicks. But it is not in Python.

It is [PlotDigitizer.com](https://plotdigitizer.com/). I have used the tool and based on my experience it is better than some others I have used earlier.

Here is a simple guide to use it:

1. Upload the image graph
2. Calibrate both axes graph - you have to do it manually
3. Pick the color of points or curves you want to extract
4. Select auto-extracting algorithms, e.g. points, curves

Done. You have extracted the data points.

You can find a more detailed guide on its website: plotdigitizer.com.